# A box contains 10 colored discs of which 2 are red

Tags: probability

A box contains 10 colored discs of which 2 are red. A man pays **10 cent** to play a game in which discs are pulled out on at a time, without replacement. If his first draw is a red disc, he will win **25 cents**. If his second draw is a red, then he will win **20 cents**. If his third draw is a red disc, then he will win **5 cent**. Calculate his expected profit or loss

My answer:

$$\left(\left(\frac{2}{10}\times0.25\right) + 
\left(\frac 19\times 0.2\right) +
\left(\frac18\times 0.05\right)\right) - (0.1) \\=
-\frac{31}{1440} = -0.0215277777777778$$

the correct answer: 9.33

Comment: For starters, your answer is in dollars and the "correct answer" is in cents.

Comment: If my first draw is a red disc, do I get to draw again?

Comment: yes you can draw again

Comment: How many disks are pulled at a time? If only one, what are the actions of a player? Must he always pull 3 disks or we are looking for best-EV strategy for him?

Comment: Below I assume we stop at the first red, which seems sensible.

Comment: he gets to pull only 3 discs. If any of the first three are red, he get a prize as mentioned in the problem. He does not get anything for the desired forth draw

Comment: So he could win 25 + 20 cents as well? And does he get 25 cents after also getting the 10 cents back, so it's a real gain? Or is it a net 15 cents?

Comment: If $9.33$ is indeed the correct answer then the player stops after drawing a red ball and the answer of @mookid is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that there are 3 'winning' cases:

- win on the first draw: $25 $ with probability $2/10$
- win on the second draw: $20$ with probability $8/10 \times 2/9$
- win on the third draw: $5 $ with probability $8/10 \times 7/9 \times 2 / 8$

The expected gain is then $9.33\dots$.

But you need to substract the cost of the game! this yields $9.33\dots - 10 = -2/3$ cent as the final result.

Comment: could you explain this part please : "win on the second draw: 20 with probability 8/10×2/9"

Comment: 8/10 is the probability not ot get a red on the first draw. After this draw there are 9 balls, 2 of which are red. Then the probability to get a red on the second draw in that case is 2/9.

Comment: However, this excludes winning at the first **and** the second draw.

Comment: indeed. but the fact is, this is the expected answer.

Comment: Yes, and it seems more reasonable to me that the player stops after drawing red. Unfortunate misunderstandings here.:(

Comment: thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1):

(revised after feedback). I'll use $n$ for a non-red disk, $r$ for a red one. So there are several outcomes:

- $P(nnn) = {8 \over 10}\times{7 \over 9}\times{6 \over 8}$ with payout 0.
- $P(nnr) = {8 \over 10}\times{7 \over 9}\times{2 \over 8}$ with payout 5 (cents).
- $P(nrn) = {8\over 10}\times{2\over 9}\times{7\over 8}$ with payout 20.
- $P(nrr) = {8 \over 10}\times{2 \over 9}\times{1 \over 8}$ with payout 20 + 5 = 25.
- $P(rnn) = {2 \over 10}\times{8 \over 9}\times{7 \over 8}$ with payout 25.
- $P(rrn) = {2 \over 10}\times{1 \over 9}\times{8 \over 8}$ with payout 25 + 20 = 45.
- $P(rnr) = {2 \over 10}\times{8 \over 9}\times{1 \over 8}$ with payout 25 + 5 = 30.

Now multiply the payouts with their probabilities, and get the expected payout. Substract 10 to get the expected profit.

Comment: no I think he can still play after the first desired draw. he gets to draw three discs regardless

Answer (score 0):

This game is equivalent to the following. All ten disks are drawn from the box randomly and without replacement. The drawn disks are laid in sequence on a table. The player receives 25 cents if the first disk is red, another 20 cents if the second disk is red, and another 5 cents if the third disk is red.

Since there are 2 red disks, the probability that after the disks are laid out, the disk in position $k$ is red is $\frac{1}{5}$, so by linearity of expectation, there is a $1$ in $5$ chance each of the three prizes is paid out. Thus the value of the game is $\dfrac{1}{5}(25+20+5)$, minus the $10$ cent entry fee, or $\dfrac{1}{5}(25+20+5)-10=0$ cents.

Answer (score 0):

His profit can be written as $P=W_{1}+W_{2}+W_{3}-10$ where $W_{i}$
denotes his winning at the $i$-th draw.

Let $R_{i}$ denote the event that the $i$-th draw is a red ball
and let $w_{i}$ denote the number of cents won if that event occurs.

Then $P\left(R_{1}\right)=P\left(R_{2}\right)=P\left(R_{3}\right)=\frac{2}{10}$
and $w_{1}=25$, $w_{2}=20$, $w_{3}=5$

$\mathbb{E}P=\mathbb{E}W_{1}+\mathbb{E}W_{2}+\mathbb{E}W_{3}-10=w_{1}P\left(R_{1}\right)+w_{2}P\left(R_{2}\right)+w_{3}P\left(R_{3}\right)-10=0$